# how can i create a dynamic page title in PHP

Tags: php

i want to create a dynamic title page for my website with php but i can't do it. please tell me better suggestion how can i learn it and also give me the tutorial link.

i explain that

here is my index.php file and another file is `header_final.php`. in the bottom of the header_final.php some button like home,how to apply,seat plan. i want to do that, when a button click then different page title is coming. that's my question. please help me...

index.php

```
<?php 
    include("include/header_final.php");

?>





<div id="page">
    <div id="page-bgtop">
        <div id="page-bgbtm">
            <div id="content">
                <div class="post">
                    <h2 class="title"><a href="#">Home</a></h2><br>

                    <div class="entry">
                        <p><img src="images/img08.jpg" width="538" height="200" alt="" /></p>


                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="post">


                </div>
                <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <!-- end #content -->











<?php

include ("include/footer_final.php");

?>
```

header_final.php

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />

<title> </title>



</head>
<body>





<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">

    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
    <li class="first current_page_item"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="apply.php">How to Apply</a></li>


        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Dynamic" is a vague, wishy washy buzzword so it isn't clear what you want to do. We don't know how your PHP is structured, so we don't know how to do much of anything within it. You haven't provided any code that shows your attempt. What have you tried? What was the expected result? What was the actual result?

Answer (score 3):

```
<head>
    <title> <?php echo "My dynamic title gotten from somewhere";?> </title>
</head>
```